# What is the standard for determining a bad review (and subsequent suspension)?

Tags: discussion, spam, review-suspension

The original answer:

> Such A Great Blog. Thank U For Sharing Useful Information. This
> Article Really Amazing And So Much Helpful For Me. In fact, I found
> the information I was looking for in your article. It’s really
> helpful. I have benefited from reading your article. Thank you very
> much. [+ LINK TO ARTICLE]

Now this is garbage.  However, the attached link was legit.  It answered the question **directly**, not adjacently as many spam links do,  nor was it a link to an ad farm (such as the usual social media click-baits.

I removed the garbage text, leaving only the link.   Then I posted a comment asking for a summary of the article as link only responses tend to disappear.

While there are certain elements of spamousity in this post, I don't see why I was suspended from the review queue for a day because of it.  (I'm not fighting the suspension.  It's one day -- who cares.)

Suspension to me is an accusation that I did something wrong, or so carelessly that I was negligent in my review.  I don't believe that was the case.

TL:DR;  Link was legit, not an ad farm and directly answered the question.  Why was I expected to identify it as spam?

Edit:  Added Options in Review (from SO, as I can't access the DIY queue right now).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is an *extremely* common pattern of spam ([here](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/320045)'s another very similar one), where the poster posts effusive but nonspecific thanks followed by a link to whatever site they're trying to spam.  It's designed to trick you into thinking it's a generic "thanks" or perhaps posting a related link.

Reviewers need to be able to spot these and flag them as spam.  Tipoffs include semi-nonsensical references to things like "your blog" or "this article" and text that's totally non-specific to the question (though the question to post the link on might be selected by related keywords—note that the question in my example above was about a "program chair" and received a link about reupholstering chairs).

Even if it weren't spam, what was left after you edited it out was [not an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/165261), and should have been, at a minimum, flagged as either "Not an answer" or "Very low quality".

Comment: The recommended actions does not include a "recommend deletion" option (see edit to original post)  I did two of the recommended actions, making a good faith attempt to repair the answer.   The UI/UX is not set up to encourage the exact action you're suggesting that I should have known to do.  In other words, I've been suspended for doing exactly what the site suggested I do.

Comment: The best way to handle it is to use the "Flag" link, flag it as spam, and submit your review using "Other action".  But I agree that's not exactly clear from the UI.  That might be useful feedback on the [Meta.SE discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013/165261) of the new review queue changes.

Comment: While the review queues are good, there should be a `First Answer` action of `Delete` with an option of `Clearly Spam`. It would make the process go much more smoothly.

Comment: @FreeMan More broadly, it's not clear to new reviewers how _anything_ that needs a flag should be handled in First Answers.  I just posted a [related feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370166/165261) earlier today regarding non-answers, but the exact same problem applies to flagging as spam.

Comment: Upvoted! (comment too)